# Add all vendor files in Vendor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Is there a way to add all files in Vendor third party libraries with sepearate `application.css` and `application.js` file?

Can I just add those two files under `Vendor` folder and `require_tree` from there like below?

```
/*
 *= require_tree assets/stylesheets/.
 */
```

Some say that I should include in `app/assets/stylsheets/application.css` file but I think there is another way like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a little bit tweak

> Sprockets uses files named index (with the relevant extensions) for a special purpose.
>
> For example, if you have a jQuery library with many modules, which is stored in lib/assets/library_name, the file lib/assets/library_name/index.js serves as the manifest for all files in this library. This file could include a list of all the required files in order, or a simple require_tree directive http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives (See 2.2.2)

That is said, say your vendor CSS directory is `vendor/assets/css/foo`, with the following files

```
/foo
  bar.css
  baz.css
```

Then you can create a file `foo/index.css` with following content

```
/= require_tree ./
```

Then you can include this lib in your main application.css as

```
/= require foo
```

**Disclaimer**

1. I have not used the above technique by myself. I just followed the guide and made assumption.
2. I myself recommend require CSS one by one as order matters in CSS. Even the files are in vendor, you can require them directly in application.css like

   ```
   /= require foo/bar
   /= require foo/baz
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your javascript file (vendor.js):

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.
```

and this in your css file (vendor.css):

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/.
```

You could put these in `app/assets/stylesheets/vendor.css` or `app/assets/javascripts/vendor.js`, and then include them in your `_head.html.erb` partial:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "vendor", :media => "screen, projection" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor" %>
```

Make sure to add these to your assets to be precompiled as well (config/environments/production.rb):

```
config.assets.precompile += ['vendor.css', 'vendor.js']
```

Also, cool username! :D

Comment: Cheers mate. I use HAML actually I think it's probably better to just include in application.js file in assets folder rather than requiring with separate configurations.

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper Will this work for you, or do you want me to change it to use the application.js file instead?

Comment: No I actually remembered there was a way to include this inside the `Vendor` folder then do `require_tree` to include the files you require only. I just can't remember all the details and where I read this...